# AJAX variable passes through to SQL but not PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, and I would greatly appreciate any advice at all on this.

On one file I have the following AJAX code:

```
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>


      var dyna = <?php echo $user_dyna; ?>;
      var limit = <?php echo $limit; ?>

      $(function() {

      $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button" display:inline-block>+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

      $(".button").on("click", function() {

        var $button = $(this);
        var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

        if ($button.text() == "+") {
        if (dyna > 0) {
          var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 5;
          dyna -= 5;
        }
        else {
            newVal = oldValue;
        }
        } else {
           // Don't allow decrementing below zero
          if (oldValue > 0) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 5;
            dyna += 5;
            } else {
            newVal = 0;
          }
          }

        if (dyna >= 0) {var dynatxt = dyna;}
        else {var dynatxt = 'Insufficient';}

        $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

        var InstAtk = parseFloat(document.getElementById('atk').value);
        var InstDef = parseFloat(document.getElementById('def').value);
        var InstHP = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hp').value);
        var sum = InstAtk + InstDef + InstHP

        document.getElementById('dynacandy').innerHTML = '<b>Dyna Candies Remaining: ' + dynatxt + '</b>';

        if (sum > limit) {
        document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = '<br><font color = "yellow">Stat total (' + sum + ') exceeds your limit of ' + limit + '</font><br>';
        }
        else {
        document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = '';
        }
      });


        $(document).ready(function() {  
            $("form").submit(function(event) {

            var Atk = document.getElementById('atk').value;
            var Def = document.getElementById('def').value;
            var HP = document.getElementById('hp').value;
            console.log(dyna);
            $.ajax({
            url: 'titan_ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {dyna: dyna, Atk: Atk, Def: Def, HP: HP},
            success: function(res){
                        console.log(res);
                        //alert('The server returned ' + res);
                    }

            });
            });
        });

    });
      </script>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <div class="titan">
    <form method="post" action="titan_ajax.php">
     <div class="numbers-row">
         &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="name">Dyna HP</label>
        <input type='number' name="hp" id="hp" value="<?=$titan['titan_hp']?>">
      </div>
     <div class="numbers-row">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label for="name">Dyna Attack</label>
        <input type="number" name="atk" id="atk" value="<?=$titan['titan_atk']?>">
      </div>
   <div class="numbers-row">
           &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<label for="name">Dyna Defense</label>
        <input type="number" name="def" id="def" value="<?=$titan['titan_def']?>">
      </div>
      <br>
    <input type = "submit" button class = "global-btn" value="Submit">
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span id="dynacandy"></span>
    <span id="limit"></span>
    <br>
    </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

And in my ajax file I have:

```
if (isset($_POST['dyna'])) {
    $newdyna = $_POST['dyna'];
    $newAtk = $_POST['Atk'];
    $newDef = $_POST['Def'];
    $newHP = $_POST['HP'];

    if ($newdyna < 0) {
        echo $newdyna;
        echo 'error';
    }
    else {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE user_items SET dyna_candy = {$newdyna} WHERE uid = {$uid}");
    }
}
```

The strange error I am getting is this - the SQL works completely fine - I've tested it a dozen times. However I can never get the PHP variable $newdyna to be echoed out, nor will the text 'error' show whenever $newdyna goes below zero. Whenever $newdyna < 0, all I get is a blank screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What datatype is dyna_candy?

Comment: It's an integer.

Comment: What value is held in the variable `dyna`? Try `console.log`-ing it in the JS, and using `var_dump` (not `echo`) on the PHP side. My suspicion is it's `null` in the PHP.

Comment: $newdyna = $_POST['dyna'];
$newAtk = $_POST['Atk'];
$newDef = $_POST['Def'];
$newHP = $_POST['HP']; print_r all these varibles and see the output

Comment: using a var_dump on dyna returned absolutely nothing. I did a var_dump($_POST), and it gave me values for Atk, Def and HP however.

Comment: Here's what i got: array(3) { ["hp"]=> string(2) "24" ["atk"]=> string(2) "19" ["def"]=> string(1) "6" }

Comment: console.log dyna before passing it in ajax

Comment: How should I add the console.log into my code @MrKhan?

Comment: console.log(dyna );  $.ajax({   before the ajax code like this

Comment: Thanks Mr Khan and yes, the variable dyna is popping up in my console (it's an integer number as well).

Comment: ok now do what i said eariler, print_r all the varibles and see the output print_r($_POST['dyna']);
print_r( $_POST['Atk']);
print_r($_POST['Def']);
print_r($_POST['HP']);

Comment: I'm getting the following:Array ( [hp] => 5 [atk] => 5 [def] => 5 ). So $_POST['dyna'] is being ommitted.

Comment: you gonna have to show me the devtools network tab on ajax call, take an ss and update your answer with it so that i can see whats being displayed

Comment: Hmm. I have a form action, so what happens is when I hit the submit button, the console log shows the dyna variable and immediately redirects away from that page. Do you want me to send you the full code instead?

Comment: sure update your question with it

Comment: the code is not complete i cannot run it without html. add html code and add screen shoot of devtools network tab as well after ajax request.

Comment: Added the HTML code. How do I capture the devtools? Which tab (Elements/Console/Sources/Network etc.) are you asking for?

Answer (score 1):

your ajax is not working properly I moved your code to a new function `sendToServer` try below HTML code...

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>


      var dyna = <?php $user_dyna=1; echo $user_dyna; ?>;
      var limit = <?php $limit=1; echo $limit; ?>;  

      $(function() {

          $(".numbers-row").append('<div class="inc button" display:inline-block>+</div><div class="dec button">-</div>');

          $(".button").on("click", function() {

            var $button = $(this);
            var oldValue = $button.parent().find("input").val();

            if ($button.text() == "+") {
            if (dyna > 0) {
              var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 5;
              dyna -= 5;
            }
            else {
                newVal = oldValue;
            }
            } else {
               // Don't allow decrementing below zero
              if (oldValue > 0) {
                var newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 5;
                dyna += 5;
                } else {
                newVal = 0;
              }
              }

            if (dyna >= 0) {var dynatxt = dyna;}
            else {var dynatxt = 'Insufficient';}

            $button.parent().find("input").val(newVal);

            var InstAtk = parseFloat(document.getElementById('atk').value);
            var InstDef = parseFloat(document.getElementById('def').value);
            var InstHP = parseFloat(document.getElementById('hp').value);
            var sum = InstAtk + InstDef + InstHP

            document.getElementById('dynacandy').innerHTML = '<b>Dyna Candies Remaining: ' + dynatxt + '</b>';

            if (sum > limit) {
                document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = '<br><font color = "yellow">Stat total (' + sum + ') exceeds your limit of ' + limit + '</font><br>';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('limit').innerHTML = '';
            }
      });

    });



    function sendToServer() {
        var Atk = document.getElementById('atk').value;
        var Def = document.getElementById('def').value;
        var HP = document.getElementById('hp').value;
        console.log(dyna);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'titan_ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {dyna: dyna, Atk: Atk, Def: Def, HP: HP},
            success: function(res){
                alert('success');
                console.log(res);
            },   
             error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                alert(msg);
            }

        });
        return false;
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
    <div class="titan">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="sendToServer();">
         <div class="numbers-row">
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="name">Dyna HP</label>
            <input type='number' name="hp" id="hp" value="<?=$titan['titan_hp']?>">
          </div>
         <div class="numbers-row">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label for="name">Dyna Attack</label>
            <input type="number" name="atk" id="atk" value="<?=$titan['titan_atk']?>">
          </div>
       <div class="numbers-row">
               &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<label for="name">Dyna Defense</label>
            <input type="number" name="def" id="def" value="<?=$titan['titan_def']?>">
          </div>
          <br>
        <input type = "submit" button class = "global-btn" value="Submit">
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <span id="dynacandy"></span>
        <span id="limit"></span>
        <br>
    </form>
    </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Ronak, thanks for your suggested solution! However, what I was looking for was a page that would redirect users away via a form action after the submit button was hit.

Comment: I was trying to show users a "success" or "fail" message based on the condition in my titan_ajax.php file. For example, if $newdyna< 0, I wanted the word "error" to be echoed back.

Comment: yes, the above code will won't redirect and do things with ajax only

Comment: Yeah, your code works in ajax. But I was wondering how to show the "success" or "fail" message as I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a work-around to my issue, by adding on to Ronak's original sendtoServer() function. This method does not involve a page redirect, but still displays the success/error messages echoed in my titan_ajax.php.

```
function sendToServer() {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(change);
    console.log(dyna);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'titan_ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
         data: {dyna: dyna, Atk: Atk, Def: Def, HP: HP},
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res);
        }   

    });

        $(".form-message").load("titan_ajax.php", {
        dyna: dyna,
        Atk: Atk,
        Def: Def,
        HP: HP,
        });
        return false;
    }
```

And in my html, I added the following tag to display the echo from 'titan_ajax.php':

```
<p class="form-message"></p>
```